# I am getting incomplete loops with broken faces/vertices

Tags: faces, selection-tools, loop

I am trying to Alt + RMB select a couple of loops but certain faces or their vertices don't get selected for some reason so the loop is left incomplete. Clicking Alt + RMB on them also does nothing. I tried deleting the faces and creating new ones but that didn't fix the problem. I'm new to Blender so there might be something I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

[image: One of the problematic faces]
[image: What I am going for]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The face you're showing is an ngon, it has more than 4 vertices, so Blender doesn't know what edge it is supposed to cut or select next:

[image]

You can make it a quad this way (for example):

[image]